# How do I create iOS app views programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am writing an app without using storyboards / xib's for creating views and am not sure of the best place to be putting my view setup code. I have tried a couple of different approaches but I'm unsure of the best way to keep view setup code separate from my controller code.

The approaches I have tried so far are:

1. Putting all my view setup code (creating and positioning buttons / labels) etc. inside a controllers `viewDidLoad` method. I'm pretty sure this is a bad way of doing things as you end up with a lot of code inside your controller.
2. Subclassing `UIView` and setting up interface elements inside the `initWithFrame` method. I then either add this view on top of my view controllers view.

   ```
   _customView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
   _customView.customLabel.text = @"Foo";
   [self.view addSubView:_customView]
   ```

or I assign the controllers view to be my `customView`.

```
_customView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
self.view = _customView;
_customView.customLabel.text = @"Foo";
```

Whilst trying to keep this question as non-subjective as possible, is there a best practice for creating iOS interfaces programmatically? Are either of these approaches a good way of keeping view code and controller code separate and reusable?

Comment: Do you need to reuse that code? If yes, subclassing or creating a category extension for a UIView will be ok. In this case, I would prefer a subclass.

Comment: Yep the aim to is get the code to be as reusable and clean as possible. I think subclassing works well, I'm just not sure of the best way to use the subclassed view. Perhaps either way is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use that view only one time, leave the code in `viewDidLoad` method. Maybe you could move the code necessary to create the view in a specific method within your controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // other code here...
    [self createView];
}
```

In addition, you could also think to override `loadView` method and put the code there if your view will be the `view` of your controller. From Apple doc.

> You can override this method in order to create your views manually.
>   If you choose to do so, assign the root view of your view hierarchy to
>   the view property.

If you need to instantiate multiple times your view, I will subclass a `UIView` and use delegate pattern to comunicate with your controller.

If you choose this approach, you need to override `layoutSubviews` method to arrange children within your view.

A clear example of this can be found in [How To Make a Custom UIView in iOS 5: A 5 Star Rating View](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view).

Comment: Ok, I can see how this is the simplest approach but doesn't it cause you to have 'fat' controllers and violate the MVC design pattern that iOS apps use?

Comment: @AFraser No, you subclass a `UIView` and not a `UIViewController`. They are different things.

Comment: @AFraser IMHO, this approach is very clean. You subclass a view. You comunicate with a controller with delagate. What do you mean with your comment?

Comment: Sorry I totally agree with your method when subclassing. I was referring to just leaving all view setup code in the UIViewController class.

Comment: @AFraser in this case you could take advantage of category extensions